# paypal integration error when respone send in db

Tags: php, paypal

I am integrating PayPal payment gateway.I'm trying to send payal response in db but amount which is given in paaypal form but amount is 0 stored in db.

Paypal form

```
<form action="<?php echo PAYPAL_URL; ?>" method="post">
                    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_ID; ?>">
                    
                    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    
                    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                 
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?>">
                    
                    <!-- Specify URLs -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_RETURN_URL; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL; ?>">
                    
                    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
                    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif">
                </form>
```

here is getting response Paypal where I inserting values in db

```
if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0 || strcasecmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) { 
     
    // Retrieve transaction info from PayPal 
    $payment_gross     = $_POST['mc_gross']; 
    $currency_code     = $_POST['mc_currency']; 
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status']; 
     
   
  
        // Insert transaction data into the database 
        $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO payments(payment_gross,currency_code,payment_status) VALUES(".$payment_gross."','".$currency_code."','".$payment_status."')"); 
    }
 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I do not believe paypal returns with POST variables, but rather GET. I've also not seen this kind of paypal integration in decades. Any reason why you are not using their JS API?

Comment: IPN uses POST variables.  A JS front end to a server integration https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server with 2 corresponding server side routes https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ would indeed be a much more modern and robust solution, but that's a completely different integration

Comment: @Ghulam, inside your if statement, please log the contents of `$_POST` and the contents of your 3 variables to a file, right before your insert call.